# Authoritatively signed certificates or own certificate for web service for Android clients with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I develop web services for enterprises and I'm use to generate my own certificates that I can install on my clients as our SW will be allways intalled in closed organizations.

Now my web service will be serving a Android App which is indeed a HTML5 & Javascript application compiled with phonegap...

Here, I don't know how to install my certificate, I found some examples in internet, but they are more or less workarounds.

Is there a way to install a certificate on Android or on the browser used by phonegap, or should I consider adquiring a certificate from a official provider?

Any help or opinion from someone which made a similar installation will be great, it is my first Android project!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On Android 4.0 and later you can install any certificate in the system trust store (needs user confirmation). On earlier versions you cannot change system trust stores. To make sure your app works in all versions you need to include the certificate in the app by creating a custom `TrustManager` initialized with your own certificate(s). For whether one can be used with Phonegap or not, check their documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I will check in this direction!